# Get type of props of a component passed in props

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I want to create a React Native component with types like this that takes a component and applies some styles to it:

```
interface Props {
  component: any;
 }
 const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({component}) => {
  const Styled = styled(component)`
    background-color: red;
  `;
 }
```

What I want is to get the prop types of the component passed in the props like this:

```
<Component component={Pressable} onPress={() => console.log("sds")} /> //Should accept this props
<Component component={Image} source={{}} /> //Should accept Image props
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a generic type using the props of the component you will use.

```js
type Props<P> = P & {
  component: (new (props: P) => React.Component<P>) | React.FC<P>;
};
function Component<P>(props: Props<P>): JSX.Element {
  return <props.component {...props}></props.component>;
}

class X extends React.Component<{ p: string }> {}
const Y: React.FC<{ p: number }> = props => <></>;
<Component component={X} p="something"></Component>;
<Component component={Y} p={1}></Component>;
```

You won't be able to use `React.FC<Props<P>>` type, unfortunately, since `P` occurs before the function expression, making TypeScript complain `cannot find name 'P'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you show how to use this component with generic?

Comment: Assuming that you have a `class X extends React.Component<{ p: string }>`, you can use `<Component component={X} p='something'>` directly.

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: I've updated the answer with fixed component type and added examples. Be sure to refresh the page if my previous solution goes wrong.

Comment: Okay, I didn't checked the last example, will try this though.